# Prefiled form for update

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, react-fullstack

When I call the update funciton from my CRUD the form its not prefiled with the previous data and it's only occur with the collection of professors the other collection alunos(students) are coded the same but it's prefiling the form with the students data.

This is the component EditarProfessor(UpdateProfessor)

```
import React,{ useEffect, useState }  from 'react'
import { Typography, TextField, Box, FormControl, InputLabel, Select, MenuItem, Button, FormLabel, FormControlLabel, FormGroup, Checkbox } from '@mui/material'
import { useParams,useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'
export default function Editar() {

  let {id} = useParams()
  const navigate = useNavigate()
 
  
const [nome, setNome] = useState("")
const [curso, setCurso] = useState("")
const [titulacao, setTitulacao] = useState("")
const [ai, setAi] = useState({ es: false, al: false, ds: false, mc: false })
const { es, al, ds, mc } = ai;



useEffect(
  ()=>{
   
    axios.get(`https://localhost:3001/professores/list/${id}`)
    .then(
      (response)=>{
      setNome(response.data.nome)
      setCurso(response.data.curso)
      setTitulacao(response.data.titulacao)
      setAi(response.data.ai)
      }
    )
    .catch(error=>console.log(error))




  }
  ,[id]
)

  
  

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    /*console.log(nome)
    console.log(curso)
    console.log(titulacao)
    console.log(ai)*/

    const professorAtualizado = {nome,curso,titulacao,ai}

    axios.put(`http://localhost:3001/professores/update/${id}`,professorAtualizado)
    .then(
      (response)=>{
        alert(`Professor ID ${response.data._id} atualizado!`)
        navigate('/listarProfessor')
      }
    )
    .catch(error=>console.log(error))

  }

  function handleCheckBox(event) {
    setAi({
      ...ai,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.checked
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Typography variant="h5" fontWeight="bold">
        Editar Professor

        <Box
          component="form"
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        >
          <TextField
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            id='nome'
            name='nome'
            value={nome}
            label="Nome Completo"
            autoFocus
            onChange={(event) => setNome(event.target.value)}
          />

          <TextField
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            id='curso'
            name='curso'
            value={curso}
            label="Curso"
            onChange={(event) => setCurso(event.target.value)}
          />
          <FormControl fullWidth sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
            <InputLabel id="select-tit-label">Titulação</InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId='select-tit-label'
              label="Titulação"
              required
              value={titulacao}
              onChange={(event) => setTitulacao(event.target.value)}
            >
              <MenuItem value="GRAD">Graduação</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="MEST">Mestrado</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="DOUT">Doutorado</MenuItem>
            </Select>

          </FormControl>

          <FormControl
            component="fieldset"
            variant="standard"
            sx={{ mt: 2, ml: 2 }}
          >
            <FormLabel
              component="legend"
              sx={{ fontSize: 12, mb: 2 }}
            >
              Áreas de Interesse
            </FormLabel>
            <FormGroup>
              <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox checked={es} name="es" onChange={handleCheckBox} />} label="Engenharia de Software" />
              <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox checked={al} name='al' onChange={handleCheckBox} />} label="Algoritmos" />
              <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox checked={ds} name='ds' onChange={handleCheckBox} />} label="Desenvolvimento de Software" />
              <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox checked={mc} name='mc' onChange={handleCheckBox} />} label="Matemática Computacional" />
            </FormGroup>
          </FormControl>

          <Box
            sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}
          >
            <Button
              type="submit"
              variant="contained"
              sx={{ my: 3 }}
            >
              Atualizar
            </Button>
          </Box>

        </Box>
      </Typography>

    </div>
  )

}
```

And here is the component to update students(EditarAlunos)

```
import { Box, Button, FormControl, InputLabel, MenuItem, Select, TextField, Typography } from '@mui/material'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'

export default function EditarAluno() {

  let {id} = useParams()
  const navigate = useNavigate();
 
  //[] vazio faz o useEffect funcionar como construtor
  useEffect(
    ()=>{
      axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/alunos/list/${id}`)
      .then(
        (response)=>{
          setNome(response.data.nome)
          setCurso(response.data.curso)
          setAno(response.data.ano)
          setIra(response.data.ira);
          
        }
      )
      .catch(error=>console.log(error))
    }
    ,[id]
  )

  const [nome, setNome] = useState("")
  const [curso, setCurso] = useState("")
  const [ano, setAno] = useState(0)
  const [ira,setIra] = useState(0);

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    /*console.log(nome)
    console.log(curso)
    console.log(ano)
    console.log(ira)*/
    const updateAluno = {nome,curso,ano,ira}

    axios.put(`http://localhost:3001/alunos/update/${id}`,updateAluno)
    .then(
      (response)=>{
        alert(`Aluno de ${response.data._id} atualizado com sucesso!`)
        navigate('/listarAluno')
      }
    )
    .catch(error=>console.log(error))

  }


  return (
    <div>
      <Typography variant='h5' fontWeight='bold'>
        Editar Aluno
      </Typography>
      <Box
        component='form'
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      >
        <TextField
          margin='normal'
          required
          fullWidth
          id='nome'
          value={nome}
          name='nome'
          label="Nome Completo"
          onChange={(event) => setNome(event.target.value)}
          autoFocus
        />
        <TextField
          type='number'
          id='ano'
          margin='normal'
          value={ano}
          name='ano'
          label='Ano de Ingresso'
          onChange={(event) => setAno(event.target.value)}
        />
         <TextField
          sx={{ml:2}}
          type='number'
          margin='normal'
          id='ira'
          value={ira}
          name='ira'
          label='IRA'
          onChange={(event) => setIra(event.target.value)}
        />
        <FormControl fullWidth sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
          <InputLabel id="select-cur-label">Curso</InputLabel>
          <Select
            labelId='select-cur-label'
            label='Curso'
            value={curso}
            onChange={(event) => setCurso(event.target.value)}
          >
            <MenuItem value="CC">Ciência da Computação</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="DD">Design Digital</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="EC">Engenharia da Computação</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="ES">Engenharia de Software</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="SI">Sistemas de Informação</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
        <Box sx={{mt:2, display:"flex", justifyContent:"center"}}>
          <Button 
          variant='contained'
          type='submit'
          >
            Atualizar
          </Button>
        </Box>




      </Box>
    </div>
  )
}
```